# keyframe does not display in Firefox or Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, animation

I made a simple animation using CSS keyframes. But it does not work in IE and Firefox. 'background-image' is not displaying in both browsers. How can I make this work in both browsers without using `background-position`?

```
@keyframes back{
    0% {
        background-image: url('../images/gandhi.jpg');
        transform: scale(1.5);
        }
    50% {
        background-image: url('../images/cv.jpg');
        }
   100% {
        background-image: url('../images/apj.jpg');
        transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Transform not working properly on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164803/css-transform-not-working-properly-on-firefox)

Comment: did you try the vendor prefixes ?

Comment: sorry to include in question that the problem is 'background-image' is not displaying in IE and Firefox

Comment: Which version of FF? [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/xp8218af/) on 59.

Comment: oops my version is 47 i updated and solved in FF,and what about IE?

Comment: I don't know about IE support for animated background image..  I know that FF supports this for a not so long time, and I am not even sure it's actually in specs, for a long time only webkit/blink did implement it.